# Java code not working due to "Cannot convert from void to int" error

Tags: java, dice

I'm very new to studying the basics of java at uni and am working on a project to return 6 random dice for each player but am coming across this error on the last line "resultRoll = JOptionPane..." Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Dice {
  public static void main(String[] args){
  }
        Dice () {
            Component f = new JFrame();
        
        Random rnd = new Random();
        String resultRoll;

        // values set 1 to 6
        int n1 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(7-1);
        int n2 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(7-1);
        int n3 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(7-1);
        int n4 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(7-1);
        int n5 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(7-1);
        int n6 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(7-1);
        
        resultRoll = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Yay! You rolled: " + n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your question and show which line it happens on.

Comment: You're showing a message dialog and trying to assign that call to a string variable. That does not make sense. Whatever you're trying to do, that is not how you do it.

Comment: Remove `resultRoll = ` from before `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set `resultRoll` before displaying the message.

```
resultRoll = n1 + " " + n2 + " " + n3 + " " + n4 + " " + n5 + " " + n6;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Yay! You rolled: " + resultRoll);
```

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you for a quick response!

Comment: @stuscot53 Happy to help.